# How to implement actionperformed on Button

Tags: java

[image]

I am implementing a `JButton` to perform an action but it's giving me an error. 
on my code i wrote

```
String EnterNumber = txtDisplay.getText() + Jbutton7.getText(); 
txtDisplay.setText(EnterNumbet) ;
```

the compiler is asking me to create a local variable call `txtDisplay` and declare it to `null`, but when i do it, it's not running.
thanks

Comment: please google it.

Comment: Please show the complete code. Since you are using txtDisplay() in an anonymous class, you need to declare it final in your method.

Comment: What are you expecting from txtDisplay.getText()? Where should "txtDisplay" come from?

Comment: please add the code where you have declared variable `txtDisplay`. Is it a type of `String`? If it is not then make a local variable like ` String txtDisplay 
 = new String("");`.

Comment: never mind, I found the problem. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `txtDisplay` as field, it seems you declared it as local variable.
I suppose that's why you can't get an access to it.

Your `button7` variable is declared as a field, but `txtDisplay` not.

Here is an example how should it be:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class SomeClass {

    private JButton jButton;
    private JTextField txtDisplay;

    public SomeClass() {
        jButton = new JButton("7");
        txtDisplay = new JTextField();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: button7 = new JButton("7");  button7.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     private JTextComponent txtDisplay;

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e ) 
   {
   
   String EnterNumber = txtDisplay.getText() + button7.getText();  
   txtDisplay.setText(EnterNumber);

Comment: No, I mean whole class in question body not in comment.